# Integrate $ x\cdot e^{i\omega x - x^2}$ from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

Can anybody help me in solving the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty x\cdot e^{i \omega x-x^2}\,dx\quad?$$

Any help/hints will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are $j$ and $\omega$ constants?

Comment: I supposed that $j$ is $\sqrt{-1}$ and $\omega$ is a constant. At least I hope ;-)

Comment: yes exactly as Umberto has written it :)

Comment: @Umberto : How can i split the integral ? As i understood from your hint is that $\int xe^{(j\omega x - x^2)} = \int xe^{ax}\int  xe^{-x^2}$? How ? Please explain a little thanking in advance

Comment: Sorry... Deleted my post. Was wrong :( my bad. I wrote that without using the brain. You cannot split the integral. But you can reduce it to the integral of the gaussian function (check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). Let me post a "correct" hint... Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Umberto: no problem at all. Waiting for your valuable comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's call our integral $I$ and write it like this
$$
I=\int_0^\infty xe^{ax-x^2}
$$
where in our case $a=j\omega$. 
Now let's consider the following integral $K$
$$
K=\int_0^\infty (a-2x)e^{ax-x^2}
$$
Now is easy to see (if there are no mistakes in my calculation) that
$$
K=-2I+a\int_0^\infty e^{ax-x^2}   \, \, \, (1)
$$
now is easy to solve $K$ by doing the variable substitution $y=ax-x^2$. 
Then in (1) the last term is simply a generic gaussian integral (also should be easy to solve).
Then from (1) one can get $I$. Sorry again for the mistaken answer.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it as it seems a bit complicated and will get back to you if i face difficulties. Thanks once again :)

Comment: No problem. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I have followed your approach which seems interesting. Here is what I did. I slightly changed the integral $I$ and wrote it like this
$$
I=\int_0^\infty xe^{ax-x^2} = \int_0^\infty xe^{-(x^2-ax)} 
$$ 
to help in limits of $K$.
Then the integral $K$ becomes
$$
K=\int_0^\infty (2x-a)e^{-(x^2-ax)}
$$
Now as you mentioned $$
K=2I-a\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2-ax)}   \, \, \, (1)
$$ solving $K$ by doing the variable substitution $y=x^2-ax$, we get $K=1$. $$I = \frac{1}{2}[1 + a\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2-ax)} dx]$$
The problem now is in the last term of (1). Guidence needed plz

Comment: Well not so easy. You need to relate the integral to the error function $\text{erf}()$. Mainly what you can do is the following. You call $c=a/2$ then you can write $x^2-ax=x^2-2cx+c^2-c^2=(x-c)^2-c^2$ that means that you rewrite the last integral in $(1)$ as $e^{c^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-(x-c)^2}dx$ and that relates to the error function. Just to give you the result (check wolfram alpha) you will get $1/2 \sqrt \pi e^{a^2/4} ( \text{erf}(a/2)+1)$. You cannot solve the integral in closed form. _If_ the extremes were $-\infty$ and $\infty$ then it would a total different story...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $j$ is the immaginary unity and $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{i\omega x - x^2}\,dx = e^{-\omega^2/4}\cdot\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{-(x-i\frac{\omega}{2})^2}\,dx$$
and:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{-(x-i\frac{\omega}{2})^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(x-i\omega/2)\cdot e^{-(x-i\frac{\omega}{2})^2}\,dx + \int_{0}^{+\infty}(i\omega/2)\cdot e^{-(x-i\frac{\omega}{2})^2}\,dx,$$
so:
 $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{-(x-i\frac{\omega}{2})^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{\omega^2/4}+\frac{i\omega}{2}\int_{-i\omega/2}^{-i\omega/2+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx,$$
and by moving the integration path in the second integral we get:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{i\omega x - x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\omega}{2}e^{-\omega^2/4}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+i\int_{0}^{\omega/2}e^{x^2}\,dx\right),$$
or:

> $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{i\omega x - x^2}\,dx = \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\int_{0}^{\omega/2}e^{x^2-\omega^2/4}\,dx\right)+i\frac{\omega\sqrt{\pi}}{4}e^{-\omega^2/4}.$$

Notice that the real part depends on the non-elementary imaginary error function, or [Dawson's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html).

Comment: In the first equality shouldnt there be another x in the exponential outside the () brackets ?

Comment: No. I just wrote $i\omega x-x^2$ as $\omega^2/4-(x-i\omega/2)^2$.

Comment: ok got it, perfect thank you

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't get it. Your answer is correct but why does your answer get vote down? Why they easily give vote down without giving any explanation what is wrong?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: It is not the first time I get a downvote for nothing, maybe someone hates me, but honestly I do not care. My solution is still right even if unaccepted and with a zero score.