# Evaluate integral $\int_0^1\sin(\pi \sqrt{-\ln x})\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

$$I=\int_0^1\sin(\pi \sqrt{-\ln x})\mathrm~ dx$$

**My efforts:**

I substitute $t=-\ln x$

And I got $$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(\pi \sqrt{t})\mathrm ~dt$$

But, how to proceed with : $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sin(\pi\sqrt{t})\mathrm dt$?

(P.S.: The result is $\dfrac{\pi^{3/2}}{2e^{\pi^2/4}}$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions instead of using unusual characters that won't render properly in many devices. Consider also that many users in this site won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: How did you get $e^{-t}\sin(π \sqrt{t})$? The substitution $t = -\ln x$ gives $dt=-1/x dx$.

Comment: @cpiegore Then $dx = -x dt = -e^{-t} dt$

Comment: You ask one question in the title, answer it, and then post a *different* question as the "real" one.  Don't you see any awkwardness in that?

Comment: There is some elegant mathematics going on here, but unfortunately the question was a PSQ and got closed (and is unlikely to be reopened given its vote score).  Would it be worthwhile to repurpose this as a Q&A?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Hi, what is a PSQ ?

Comment: Poorly stated question.

Comment: Duplicate: [Integrate $ x\cdot e^{i\omega x - x^2}$ from $0$ to $\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744853)

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\sqrt{-\ln x}$, hence $x=e^{-t^2}$. Integration by part, and we get

$$I=\int_\infty^0\sin(\pi t)~d(e^{-t^2})=\sin(\pi t)~d(e^{-t^2})\bigg|_\infty^0-\pi\int_\infty^0\cos(\pi t)\cdot e^{-t^2}dt=\pi\int^\infty_0\cos(\pi t)\cdot e^{-t^2}dt$$

This is a Gaussian-like integral and can be [solved by many ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317249/gaussian-like-integral-int-0-infty-e-x2-cos-a-x-mathrmdx?noredirect=1)

$$\int_0^\infty \cos(ax)\cdot e^{-x^2}~dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\,e^{-a^2/4}$$

therefore,

$$\boxed{\int_0^1\sin(\pi \sqrt{-\ln x})\mathrm~ dx=\frac{\pi\sqrt\pi}{2}\,e^{-\pi^2/4}}$$